# Using SQL to determine whether a user has previously seen a question

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, feature-engineering

I have a table which looks like the following:

[image: Before]

I would like to add a new feature 'question_seen', which determines whether a user has previously seen the particular question. The table with the new feature will look like this:

[image: After]

How can I create this new feature using SQL commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a window function with conditional logic:

```
select t.*,
       (row_number() over (partition by user_id, question_id order by row_id) > 1) as question_seen
from t;
```

Note:  This returns a boolean rather than `0`/`1`.  I prefer booleans for a flag, but it is easy to change to `0`/`1`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select *, 
  count(1) over user_question_history - 1 question_seen
from data
window user_question_history as (partition by user_id, question_id order by row_id)
```